# Insert JTable into JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jxtreetable

I have a `JXTreeTable` where each row should be a name, a `JTable` with some saved data and a `Save JButton`. I am having problem displaying properly the tables and buttons. 
I have overridden the **getColumnClass**:

```
        model = new DefaultTreeTableModel(root, Arrays.asList(headings)) {

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            if (column == 1) {
                return JTable.class;
            } else if (column == 3) {
                return JButton.class;
            } else {
                return String.class;
            }
        }
    };
```

but the tables appear as a description of their characteristics:

```
userTable$2[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=251658568,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,autoCreateColumnsFromModel=true,autoResizeMode=AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS,cellSelectionEnabled=false,editingColumn=-1,editingRow=-1,gridColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=128,g=128,b=128],preferredViewportSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=450,height=400],rowHeight=16,rowMargin=1,rowSelectionAllowed=true,selectionBackground=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=51,g=153,b=255],selectionForeground=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255],showHorizontalLines=true,showVerticalLines=true]
```

Is there a specific way I should insert the JTable as cell data? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1. `Is there a specific way I should insert the JTable as cell data?` - I think that SwingX site has bunch code examples, incl. description and links to APIs  2. `Thank you for your help!` - glad if help you, 3. btw question in this form isn't answerable on SO